# Not refreshing second select dropdown list

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, materialize

I am new in web development, I appreciate your help with this problem. I am trying to build and HTML form using Apps Script, materialize CSS and JavaScript. I have two dependent selects, the first one with id "tipo" and the second with id "nov". These two are dependent, if i choose in the first select an option, only for the second select must appears only the options that belongs to that category. for example, when i select in the first dropdown the option calls "servicios publicos" the second select only must show the options: agua, luz, energia, gas and telef/internet.  The problem is in the second select with id "nov" its not refreshing, only appears the option calls "agua", but the select its not working, when you clicked it.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
  var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateWords).getWords();

  document.getElementById("frmRegister").addEventListener("submit", empres);

  document.getElementById('nov').addEventListener("click", 'select');

});

function populateWords(words) {

  var autocomplete = document.getElementById('pto');
  var instances2 = M.Autocomplete.init(autocomplete, {
    data: words
  });


}


function empres(e) {

  // prevenir un evento por defecto 
  e.preventDefault();

  var userInfo = {};

  userInfo.punto = document.getElementById("pto").value;
  userInfo.tiponov = document.getElementById("tipo").value;
  userInfo.novedad = document.getElementById("nov").value;
  userInfo.check = document.getElementById("ch").value;
  userInfo.detalle = document.getElementById("textarea1").value;



  google.script.run.registroEmp(userInfo);
  document.getElementById("pto").value = "";
  document.getElementById("tipo").value = "";
  document.getElementById("nov").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ch").value = "";
  document.getElementById("textarea1").value = "";


  var selectList = document.getElementById("tipo");
  selectList.selectedIndex = 0;
  M.FormSelect.init(selectList);

  var selectList2 = document.getElementById("nov");
  selectList2.selectedIndex = 0;
  M.FormSelect.init(selectList2);

  var selectList3 = document.getElementById("ch");
  selectList3.selectedIndex = 0;
  M.FormSelect.init(selectList3);
  //var datePicker =document.getElementById("fecha");
  //datePicker.value ="";
  //M.Datepicker.init(datePicker);

}
```

```css
* {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

.form-row {
  margin-bottom: 0px;

}

.row1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 2px;


}

.warning-bar {
  visibility: hidden;
}

img {

  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.page-footer {

  background: black;
  border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;

}

.container-footer {
  color: black;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left:

}

.page-footer.footer-copyright {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;

}

.div.footer-copyright {
  color: black;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;


}

.footer.page-footer {
  background-color: black;
}

.page-footer .footer-copyright {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;

}

p.black-text-copyright {
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-align: left;

}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #FFFFFF;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #17202A;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

h3 {

  text-align: center;

}

btn {

  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;

}

h5 {

  text-align: center;

}

.title {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

h4 {

  text-align: center;

}



}

body {

  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/3717291/pexels-photo-3717291.jpeg");
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;

}

button {
  margin-bottom: 20px;


}

html {

  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;

}

.login {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 16px auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;

}

}


.frmHome {

  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

}

.select-wrapper .caret {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  z-index: 0;
  fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);

}

.login-triangle {
  width: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #1ABC9C;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.login-header {
  background: #1ABC9C;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.login-container {
  background: #FDFEFE;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid #D5D8DC;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.textarea.materialize-textarea {

  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_Self">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <?!= include("page-css"); ?>



</head>

<body>
    <img style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:auto; margin:0; padding:0; background:https://images.pexels.com/photos/3717291/pexels-photo-3717291.jpeg"
        src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3717291/pexels-photo-3717291.jpeg">
    <div class="login">
        <div class="login-triangle"></div>
        <h2 class="login-header">Registro Novedades</h2>
        <form id="frmRegister" class="login-container">


            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <i style="color:#1ABC9C" class="material-icons prefix">search</i>
                    <input type="text" id="pto" class="autocomplete">
                    <label for="pto">Consulta el punto de servicio</label>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <select id="tipo" onchange="ChangeCarList()">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="SP">Servicios Públicos</option>
                        <option value="SG">Seguridad</option>
                        <option value="AD">Administración</option>
                        <option value="CV">Convivencia</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="tipo">Selecciona el tipo de novedad</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <select id="nov"></select>
                    <label>Novedad</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script>
                var carsAndModels = {};
                carsAndModels['SP'] = ['Agua', 'Aseo', 'Energia', 'Gas', 'Telef/Internet'];
                carsAndModels['SG'] = ['Hurto a residencias', 'Intervención Policia Nal', 'Orden Público',
                    'Lesiones Personales', 'Alarma', 'Daños Infraestruc/Bienes'
                ];
                carsAndModels['AD'] = ['M6', 'X5', 'Z3'];

                function ChangeCarList() {
                    var carList = document.getElementById("tipo");
                    var modelList = document.getElementById("nov");
                    var selCar = carList.options[carList.selectedIndex].value;
                    while (modelList.options.length) {
                        modelList.remove(0);
                    }
                    var cars = carsAndModels[selCar];
                    if (cars) {
                        var i;
                        for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
                            var car = new Option(cars[i], i);
                            modelList.options.add(car);
                        }
                    }
                }
            </script>




            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <select id="ch">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Generar Alerta</option>

                        <option>Si</option>
                        <option>No</option>


                    </select>
                    <label>¿Desea generar alerta de pánico?</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                <label for="textarea1">Ingrese el detalle del evento</label>
            </div>


            <button style="width:100%; margin-top:20px;" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small" type="submit"
                name="action">Enviar
                <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
            </button>



        </form>

    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>


    <?!= include("page-js"); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: the select input is rendered with Materialize on page load, it adds HTML elements to you're initial code to make the UI looks the way it looks,

All you have to do is to trigger this after you add the select options, so I moved this code from Javascript file ( which triggers only once at the beginning ) into the `ChangeCarList()` so that the Materialize can create the proper dropdown with new options.

```js
var selectList2 = document.getElementById("nov");
selectList2.selectedIndex = 0;
M.FormSelect.init(selectList2);
```

Since you already have the variable `modelList` contains the `nov`, I just used it instead of re-selecting it.

I hope this is the result you were looking for, Good Luck.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
  var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);

  //google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateWords).getWords();

  document.getElementById("frmRegister").addEventListener("submit", empres);

  // document.getElementById('nov').addEventListener("click", 'select');

});

function populateWords(words) {

  var autocomplete = document.getElementById('pto');
  var instances2 = M.Autocomplete.init(autocomplete, {
    data: words
  });


}


function empres(e) {


  e.preventDefault();

  var userInfo = {};

  userInfo.punto = document.getElementById("pto").value;
  userInfo.tiponov = document.getElementById("tipo").value;
  userInfo.novedad = document.getElementById("nov").value;
  userInfo.check = document.getElementById("ch").value;
  userInfo.detalle = document.getElementById("textarea1").value;



  google.script.run.registroEmp(userInfo);
  document.getElementById("pto").value = "";
  document.getElementById("tipo").value = "";
  document.getElementById("nov").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ch").value = "";
  document.getElementById("textarea1").value = "";


  var selectList = document.getElementById("tipo");
  selectList.selectedIndex = 0;
  M.FormSelect.init(selectList);

  var selectList3 = document.getElementById("ch");
  selectList3.selectedIndex = 0;
  M.FormSelect.init(selectList3);
  //var datePicker =document.getElementById("fecha");
  //datePicker.value ="";
  //M.Datepicker.init(datePicker);

}
```

```css
* {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

.form-row {
  margin-bottom: 0px;

}

.row1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 2px;


}

.warning-bar {
  visibility: hidden;
}

img {

  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.page-footer {

  background: black;
  border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;

}

.container-footer {
  color: black;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left:

}

.page-footer.footer-copyright {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;

}

.div.footer-copyright {
  color: black;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;


}

.footer.page-footer {
  background-color: black;
}

.page-footer .footer-copyright {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;

}

p.black-text-copyright {
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-align: left;

}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #FFFFFF;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #17202A;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

h3 {

  text-align: center;

}

btn {

  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;

}

h5 {

  text-align: center;

}

.title {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

h4 {

  text-align: center;

}



}

body {

  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/3717291/pexels-photo-3717291.jpeg");
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;

}

button {
  margin-bottom: 20px;


}

html {

  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;

}

.login {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 16px auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;

}

}


.frmHome {

  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

}

.select-wrapper .caret {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  z-index: 0;
  fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);

}

.login-triangle {
  width: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #1ABC9C;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.login-header {
  background: #1ABC9C;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.login-container {
  background: #FDFEFE;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid #D5D8DC;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.textarea.materialize-textarea {

  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.input-field input {
  padding-left: 10px
}

.select-wrapper input.select-dropdown {
  text-indent: 25px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_Self">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


</head>

<body>
    <img style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:auto; margin:0; padding:0; background:https://images.pexels.com/photos/3717291/pexels-photo-3717291.jpeg"
        src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3717291/pexels-photo-3717291.jpeg">
    <div class="login">
        <div class="login-triangle"></div>
        <h2 class="login-header">Registro Novedades</h2>
        <form id="frmRegister" class="login-container">


            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <i style="color:#1ABC9C" class="material-icons prefix">search</i>
                    <input type="text" id="pto" class="autocomplete">
                    <label for="pto">Consulta el punto de servicio</label>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <select id="tipo" onchange="ChangeCarList()">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="SP">Servicios Públicos</option>
                        <option value="SG">Seguridad</option>
                        <option value="AD">Administración</option>
                        <option value="CV">Convivencia</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="tipo">Selecciona el tipo de novedad</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s12 nov-select">
                    <select id="nov">
                    </select>
                    <label>Novedad</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script>
                var carsAndModels = {};
                carsAndModels['SP'] = ['Agua', 'Aseo', 'Energia', 'Gas', 'Telef/Internet'];
                carsAndModels['SG'] = ['Hurto a residencias', 'Intervención Policia Nal', 'Orden Público',
                    'Lesiones Personales', 'Alarma', 'Daños Infraestruc/Bienes'
                ];
                carsAndModels['AD'] = ['M6', 'X5', 'Z3'];

                function ChangeCarList() {
                    var carList = document.getElementById("tipo");
                    var modelList = document.getElementById("nov");
                    var selCar = carList.options[carList.selectedIndex].value;
                    while (modelList.options.length) {
                        modelList.remove(0);
                    }

                    var cars = carsAndModels[selCar];
                    if (cars) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
                            var car = new Option(cars[i], i);
                            modelList.options.add(car)
                        }
                    }

                    modelList.selectedIndex = 0;
                    M.FormSelect.init(modelList);                    
                }

            </script>




            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <select id="ch">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Generar Alerta</option>

                        <option>Si</option>
                        <option>No</option>


                    </select>
                    <label>¿Desea generar alerta de pánico?</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                <label for="textarea1">Ingrese el detalle del evento</label>
            </div>


            <button style="width:100%; margin-top:20px;" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small" type="submit"
                name="action">Enviar
                <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
            </button>



        </form>

    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>


    <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>



<div class="input-field col s12">
    <div class="select-wrapper">

        <select id="tipo" onchange="ChangeCarList()" tabindex="-1">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="SP">Servicios Públicos</option>
            <option value="SG">Seguridad</option>
            <option value="AD">Administración</option>
            <option value="CV">Convivencia</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <label for="tipo">Selecciona el tipo de novedad</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Great!! thanks for your comments, its works!! many thanks!!

Comment: only one question, when i try to select the second option of any category i cant selected. Do you know why?

Comment: Sorry for the misleading, I updated the code. try it again, and if you still need help, don't hesitate to ask. good luck.

Comment: @JorgeEnriqueRomeroSaray what device are you have select problems? There is a browser bug in iOS13

Comment: No problem, it works, great! many thanks for your help. Only i have one question, when i complete the form in google sheet in the the field that corresponds to second select "nov" no put the text, put the position 1, 2, 3... Its there a way to put the text on the options not the position?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully understand you question. can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, Hi, im trying for this html form, sumbit all options into a google sheet. Im see, when i submit this form, all fields are put correctly in a google sheet. Except for the second select ModelList, puts in the sheet only the position not the texts. As following appears in the sheet, if you look in the field Nov: not puts in sheet the text, only put the position on the option in modelist                                             Date: 25/6/2020 16:57:32 Point of Service: TELEPERFORMANCE COLOMBIA SAS Tipo: Administración Nov: 1 Details: No test

Comment: i have this: function registroEmp(userInfo){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
  ws.appendRow([new Date(), userInfo.punto, userInfo.tiponov, userInfo.novedad,  userInfo.check, userInfo.detalle]);

Comment: and this
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("frmRegister").addEventListener("submit", empres);              -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: And this function empres(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   var userInfo = {};
   userInfo.punto = document.getElementById("pto").value;
   userInfo.tiponov = document.getElementById("tipo").value;
   userInfo.novedad = document.getElementById("nov").value;
   userInfo.check = document.getElementById("ch").value;
   userInfo.detalle = document.getElementById("textarea1").value;

Comment: and this: google.script.run.registroEmp(userInfo);
    document.getElementById("pto").value = "";
    document.getElementById("tipo").value = "";
    document.getElementById("nov").value = "";
    document.getElementById("ch").value = "";
    document.getElementById("textarea1").value = "";
    var selectList = document.getElementById("tipo");
    selectList.selectedIndex = 0;
    M.FormSelect.init(selectList);
    var selectList2 = document.getElementById("nov");
    selectList2.selectedIndex = 0;
    M.FormSelect.init(selectList2);
       }

Comment: try this:   replace ` var car = new Option(cars[i], i);` width ` var car = new Option(cars[i], cars[i]);`

Comment: you can find it in the HTML code in `
                    if (cars) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
                            var car = new Option(cars[i], cars[i]);
                            modelList.options.add(car)
                        }
                    }
`